# How to append button dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to make dynamic button with respect to the reult.If i click a button it retrieves the results as in buttons.

```
$('#but').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
         type:"POST",
         url:"tab.php",
         data:{id:this.id},
         success:function (result){
         alert(response);
         $("#show").html(result);

         }
         });

           });
```

my tab.php

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("show tables");


while($tbl_str = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
 echo ucwords($tbl_str[0]);    
}
?>
```

Comment: what response you are getting in result ?

Comment: am getting table name and want to append it to buttons

Comment: you want to append table into button?

Comment: still not clear with your question....you are getting table name say 'abc', now what you want this in button. Please elaborate ?

Comment: yes,for eg: am getting table names as employee,travels etc.I want to make the name as buttons dynamically.

Comment: so is not a table, but an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In php file, returned the array in `json` format as used in ajax request.

```
$result = mysql_query("show tables");
$array = array();
while($tbl_str = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $array[] = ucwords($tbl_str[0]);    
}
$output['result'] = $array;
echo json_encode($output);
exit;
```

Your ajax function, Use `dataType:'json'`

```
$.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   dataType:'json',
   url:"tab.php",
   data:{id:this.id},
   success:function (result){
      //alert(result.result);
      $.each( result.result, function( index, value ){
            //alert(value);
            $("#show").append("<button>"+value+"</button>");
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: getting error-TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a

Comment: please post your response array here.

Comment: Employee Travels Stores

Comment: is this an array? post exact array with syntax.

Comment: pls check i edited my qns.

Comment: Have you tried that...is it working ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can do this way:
Instead of

```
$("#show").html(result);
```

Use

```
$("#show").append("<button>"+result+"</button>");
```

You don't have to change `html()` to `append()`, but in this case it won't replace the existing buttons, so I think it fits you better

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have buttons separately, right: if the returned result is `employee,travels` then you need 2 buttons `employee` and `travels`, if so I would make one function which creates button with the name:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#but').click(function() 
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "tab.php",
            data: {id: this.id},
            success: function(result) 
            {
                makeButtons(result);
            }
        });
    });


    function makeButtons(buttonsString)
    {
        // you can clear #show tag
        $('#show').html('');

        var buttonsArray = buttonsString.split(',');

        for(var i = 0; i < buttonsArray.length; i++)
        {
            makeButton(buttonsArray[i]);
        }
    }


    function makeButton(buttonName)
    {
        // you can also add some events atc.. 
        // if u want clicking this button to do something
        $('#show').append('<button>' + buttonName + '</button>');
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Am getting only one button with all tablenames

Comment: can you log in `makeButtons` function what is passed to `buttonsString` param??